Pg_restore runs ALTER TABLE .. OWNER TO ignoring pg_dump --no-owner option
I'm using an mac mini m1 and postgresl14 on it for a database migration.
For the migration a change of the owner is necessary.
To export the dump needed I log in on my mac, call sudo su to become root and use the following cmd:
pg_dump -Fc --no-owner --encoding=UTF8 -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres [[dbname]] -n [[schemaname]] > upload.bak

[[dbname]] and [[schemaname]] are placeholders here.
After that, I upload the upload.bak file to my server instance of ubuntu24.
On that ubuntu server instance I try to import the file via
pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 -U [[username]] -d [[dbname]] -n [[schemaname]]

The import begins to run, but it says:
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: 
ERROR:  role "[[old_role]]" does not exist
Command was: ALTER TABLE [[schemaname]].[[tablename]] OWNER TO [[old_role]];

Seems as if the "-O" approx. "--no-owner" param above is completely ignored, even though I called pg_dump as root and postgres user.
How to instruct pg_dump to not export the "update role" statements?

Reading the docs would be a start pg_dump: --no-owner ... his option is ignored when emitting an archive (non-text) output file. For the archive formats, you can specify the option when you call pg_restore..

Works as designed

@AdrianKlaver Would you mind posting that as an answer? I know it's kind of a duplicate of this, but here the problem was that pg_dump --no-owner is ignored quietly and user has to know the option doesn't work with the -Fc and has to be repeated with pg_restore, since neither of these will detect or communicate the incompatibility. The other thread asks "how do I do that", this one asks "why does this specific option have no effect" - I think it might be worth keeping.

Well, then the design is bullshit. Sorry.

From:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html

--no-owner [...] This option is ignored when emitting an archive (non-text) output file. For the archive formats, you can specify the option when you call pg_restore.

You specified pg_dump -Fc which is one of the archive formats so --no-owner will be ignored. To have this work you will need to add --no-owner to the pg_restore command as in:
pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 --no-owner -U [[username]] -d [[dbname]] -n [[schemaname]]
UPDATE
As to text vs archive, from pg_dump:

Dumps can be output in script or archive file formats. Script dumps are plain-text files containing the SQL commands required to reconstruct the database to the state it was in at the time it was saved.


-F format
--format=format


Selects the format of the output. format can be one of the following:


p
plain


Output a plain-text SQL script file (the default).

So everything else is an archive format.
From same link under:
Examples

To dump a database called mydb into an SQL-script file:

$ pg_dump mydb > db.sql

To reload such a script into a (freshly created) database named newdb:

$ psql -d newdb -f db.sql

To dump a database into a custom-format archive file:

$ pg_dump -Fc mydb > db.dump

To reload an archive file into a (freshly created) database named newdb:

$ pg_restore -d newdb db.dump

Thanks. Unfortunately the documentation is really worse here. The definition of what is a non-text archive, and which not is missing. You find it out, if you think about, but it is missing.
Furthermore: it took me days to find out, how to transfer data from one instance to another one. There is only one way i found, but this is horrific try and error, until you got it, at least for postgres newbies like me.
But yes: it works, if you have enough time to search and guessing.
(there is NO error that the -O option is used invalid. Also, when importing data there is a silent loop forever)

See UPDATE to question.

Thanks, Adrian. As soon as I’m back at home I gonna try this. As far as I remember this did not work, but I’m not sure. I’ll give you feedback! Thx !!!
